# Accessing iOS QuickType suggestions in an app

Tags: ios, quicktype

I want my app to know what the QuickType suggestions are. QuickType has gotten more context-aware recently, and you can type something like "auto r" and expect to see "repair" and "racing" as suggestions.

I've found `UITextChecker`, which can suggest completions for a single word but isn't context-aware. From http://nshipster.com/uitextchecker/ :

```
let textChecker = UITextChecker()
let partial = "auto r"
let completions = textChecker.completionsForPartialWordRange(
    NSRange(0..<partial.utf16.count), inString: partial,
    language: "en_US")
print(completions) # prints "[]"
```

I've tried getting a `UILexicon` from a `UIInputViewController`, but Apple's documentation says "Apple intends for you to consider the words in a lexicon object as supplementary to an autocorrection/suggestion lexicon of your own design" ([link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilexicon)). So I guess this isn't the smart QuickType suggestions. It's not giving me any suggestions (tested in simulator):

```
let ivc = UIInputViewController()
ivc.textDocumentProxy.insertText("auto r")

ivc.requestSupplementaryLexiconWithCompletion { (lexicon:UILexicon) in
    print("Called") // prints "Called"
    print(lexicon.entries) // prints "[]", no suggestions
}
```

Does Apple not intend to expose the QuickType suggestions to us?